# Why is there an error when I try to load an image?

Tags: java, image

So, I have made a class called TileDrawer.java, which is supposed to load in a BufferedImage with the following code:

```
BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;    

public void initSpriteSheet() {
        try {
                this.spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("resources\\spritesheet.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

but when I try to run the method after initializing the object, it gives me this error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

---

This is my current full code for the TileDrawer class:

```
package mainGame;
        
//imports
                
public class TileDrawer {
        BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;    
                
         
        public void initSpriteSheet() {
                try {
                        this.spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("resources\\spritesheet.png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }        
        
        //irrelevant methods were here
}
```

and I also have this class, called GamePanel with the following code:

```
package mainGame;

//imports

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        
        Thread gameThread;
        
        TileDrawer tileDrawer = new TileDrawer();

        //vars
        
        public GamePanel() {} //game panel
        
        public void startGameThread() {
                tileDrawer.initSpriteSheet(); //  <---  here                                                     
                gameThread = new Thread(this);
                gameThread.start();
        }
                 
        @Override
        public void run() {
                //stuff to make a functioning loop

                while (gameThread != null) {
                        
                        //more loop stuff

                        if (delta >= 1) { //delta is only used to cap the framerate

                                update();
                                repaint();
                                
                                //even more loop stuff
                        }
                }
        }

        public void update() {
                //update stuff here
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

                //drawing stuff goes here

                g2.dispose();

        }
}
```

---

Some background info:

- I am using Debian Linux
- The directory looks like this:

```
MyGame
|------build
|      |------(Compiled java files)
|------src
|      |------Main.java (irrelevant)
|      |------GamePanel.java
|      |------TileDrawer.java
|      |------resources
|      |      |------spriteSheet.png
```

- I am not using an IDE to compile my code, I am simply using these commands:

```
cd /home/{my username}/MyGame/
javac -d ./build src/Main.java src/GamePanel.java src/TileDrawer.java
cd build
java mainGame.Main
```

---

All of these things I tried, but none of them worked when I tried to implement them:

- changing the file path into singular normal slashes
- changing the file path into singular normal slashes and putting one at the front
- using a normal Image file instead of a BufferedImage
- putting the image file into the same directory as the java file

---

Any help on how to fix my problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get the image as a resource, not as a file.

Comment: The `File` class will look for the file in the OS, therefore if you are in the `MyGame` folder and your image is inside the `resource` folder running it from there you need to add the `src` folder to your path. This is the first part of the problem. @HovercraftFullOfEels beat me to it for the second part, since you are adding the file as a resource, you access it as a resource. Though I have to ask to Hover, will it work if he is not creating a Jar file for it?

Comment: I thought linux was case sensitive - file names don't match.  `spritesheet.png` vs `spriteSheet.png`

Comment: @67af7af3-67f3-48bf-98c5-d9155c Good point! That's also a problem

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: The `new File("resources\\spritesheet.png")` is *relative* path. It is relative to *current directory*. To know what is *location* of current director see result of `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` (it may not be what you think it is). You can also know location from which your application tries to read your file via printing result of `new File("resources\\spritesheet.png").getAbsolutePath()`. Try to compare that result with actual path of your file, but since you got error they can't match.

Comment: If you want to read from locations relative to location of project (or JAR from which it is run) you should *load them as resources*. Here is example of question on that subject [Loading resources like images while running project distributed as JAR archive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9864267)

Comment: Since your question isn't closed, maybe your edit should be an answer? Also, your 3 points, can you include the code that produces those results? eg, how did you "I loaded in the image as a resource instead of an image " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all the help! If anyone sees this in the future, here is what I changed to make it work.

First, I moved the resource folder out of the src folder and into the root folder so it could be accessed (thanks to [Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos) for that).

Then, I loaded in the image as a resource instead of a file, and I fixed the capitalization error. (thanks to [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75000297/edit#:%7E:text=Hovercraft%20Full%20Of%20Eels) and 
[67af7af3-67f3-48bf-98c5-d9155c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17856705/67af7af3-67f3-48bf-98c5-d9155c) for that, respectively).

In the URL, I changed the `\\`'s into `/`'s, and added one in front of it.

In total, I changed this:

```
this.spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("resources\\spritesheet.png"));
```

Into this:

```
this.spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/spriteSheet.png"));
```

and I moved the resources folder into the root folder.

Once again, thank you all for your help!

note: the '`this.`' in the above code examples in unnecessary, but it works either way.